get filenames from download folder with API34
I have a small test application to retrieve the file names of the download folder on the device.
To test, I used a file manager to copy a file called "test.xls" into the download folder. The file is not hidden and is located directly in the folder, not a subfolder.
I am working with API34. According to the Android pages, you do not need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for the download folder, but even if I want to do this, I cannot do it under API34, or I am not aware of how this works with API34.
Of course, this would work with the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but then the final app will not be released in the App Store (Play Store rejected the release).
I tried the following code, but with this code I do not get the file names from the download folder.
What is the problem? Do you have any suggestions or solutions for this?
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File testfile = new File(directory + "/test.xls");
    if (testfile.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getFilenames: File exists");  // <-- the file exists
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "getFilenames: File exists not");
    }
    File[] files;
    files = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls");
        }
    });


You only have rights to access files in Download/ that your app installation created. Files created by other apps, including previous installations of your app, will be inaccessible, unless you use the Storage Access Framework
